# How to start some searches at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently working on a frontend for visualizing the results out ouf some searches in foreign systems. At the moment the programm is asking one system by another and only continues, when alle foreign systems have answered.
The frontend is written in Vaadin 13 and this should be able to refresh the page by push.

I have six controller classes for six foreign systems to question and want to start all questions at the same time without having to wait for the privious controller to finish.

My problem is that I can't find a tutorial which helps me with this special problem. All tutorials are about starting the same process for more than once but at the same time.

This is how I start the searches at the moment:

```
public static void performSingleSearch(ReferenceSystem referenceSystem, String searchField, List<String> searchValues, SystemStage systemStage) throws Exception {

    if(!isAvailable(referenceSystem, systemStage)) return;
    Map<String, ReferenceElement> result = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        Class<?> classTemp = Class.forName(referenceSystem.getClassname());
        Method method = classTemp.getMethod("searchElements", String.class , List.class, SystemStage.class);
        result = (Map<String, ReferenceElement>) method.invoke(classTemp.newInstance(), searchField, searchValues, systemStage);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        return;
    }
    if(result != null) orderResults(result, referenceSystem);
}
```

I hope you can provide me an tutorial on how to, or better a book over multithreading.

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the simplest approach is using `CompletableFuture`. Ignoring your atrocious use of reflection, I'm going to assume

```
interface ReferenceSystem {
    public Map<String,ReferenceElement> searchElements(List<String> args);
}

List<ReferenceSystem> systems = getSystems();
List<String> searchArguments = getSearchArguments();
```

so you can do

```
List<CompletableFuture<Map<String, ReferenceElement>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (ReferenceSystem system : systems) {
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> system.searchElements(searchArguments)));
}
```

or with Java 8 Streams

```
List<CompletableFuture<Map<String, ReferenceElement>>> futures =
    systems.stream()
           .map(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                     () -> system.searchElements(searchArguments)))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now the `futures` contains a list of futures which will eventually return the `Map` you're looking for; you can access them with `#get()` which will block until the result is present:

```
for (CompletableFuture<Map<String,ReferenceElement>> future : futures) {
    System.out.printf("got a result: %s%n", future.get());
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't completely understand your code. But maybe I have completely fucked up mine. ReferenceSystem is an enum therefore the reflection every enum gets his class, where it's searchElements function is hidden. So if you want a new class for search you have to make a class based on an interface and put it in the enum.

Comment: @DanielBecker You can do that by letting your `enum` implement an interface and then implement it using pretty much the code you have, without the reflection. You'd need to post this as a new question, since this one was about how to multithread your queries.

Answer (score 0):

With your primitive case all you would need is either list of threads and just wait on them to finish or even easier, use thread pool and use that:

```
private static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6); // change to whatever you want

public static void someMethod() {
    queueActions(Arrays.asList(
            () -> {
                try {
                    performSingleSearch(null, null, null, null); // fill your data
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }, 
            () -> {
                try {
                    performSingleSearch(null, null, null, null); // fill your data #2 etc
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
    ));
}

public static void queueActions(List<Runnable> actions) {
    Semaphore wait = new Semaphore((-actions.size()) + 1);

    for (Runnable action : actions) {
        service.execute(() -> {
            try {
                action.run();
            } finally {
                wait.release();
            }
        });
    }

    try {
        wait.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
```

The question remains whether you want to orders be executed at the same time or one at a time or something else (join orders into one big order etc).

Comment: Why Runnable, doesn't OP expects a Map<String, ReferenceElement>? Instead of using Arrays.asList, a simple for-loop iterating over ReferenceSystems would have been a better.

Comment: op's method does not return anything, that's why it's runnable. Also simple loop for what, filling the runnables? Yes technically you can put it in one loop and such but I wanted to keep his flow as similar as possible

Comment: Your solutions would be great, if it wasn't fixed. I don't know how many threads the user want's to start. I don't even know how many threads there are possible. The Program should stay scalable so I don't want to fix this part.